# Getting Webpack CSS and React working together

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have my webpack config loaders as like this:

```
//config for css
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
{ test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
{ test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" }
```

and in my React component I have:

```
import styles from "../../../css/style.css"
```

and my `style.css` looks like:

```
#box {
}
```

but in my react component if I refer to `styles` its just returning `{}`, I expect it should have `box` key. But it doesn't, where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need enable [`css-modules`](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#css-modules)

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader?modules"
```

[`Example`](http://www.webpackbin.com/4JjSIjKDW)